# Upgrade MOSS 2007 Publishing Site Template to SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

I have looked everywhere and tried everything but thus far I am unsuccessful at getting a my Template working on my SharePoint 2010 site.  I did a detach/attach upgrade.

Everything is working okay except for that I can't create a new site.  I tried downloading my .stp from my 2007 site.  I renamed it to a .cab.  Made the necessary edits in the manifest.xml.  Remade my .cab file and then renamed it a .stp and uploaded it to Solutions in my SharePoint 2010 site but it still does not work.

Everything loads fine but when I am make it available and a Site Template it doesn't stick.  I get a blank page when click New Site.

Answer (score 0):

Publishing sites are not meant to be used as .STP files - the implications are beyond the site template. The recomanded ways are either to create your own site definition (http://www.sharepointnutsandbolts.com/2007/08/creating-deploying-and-updating-custom.html or http://onlinecoder.blogspot.ch/2012/05/variations-in-sharepoint-2010-bring.html) or a Web Template.

If you choose to go that way, make sure you go through this article http://sharepointchick.com/archive/0001/01/01/site-definitions-vs.-webtemplates.aspx to understand the pros and cons.